# Replace characters to right of string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, replace

I am in need of solving a problem for my project.

I need to clean up an address field in PostgreSQL by removing everything to the right of a street name.

And I have found it here: [PostgreSQL replace characters to right of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490614/postgresql-replace-characters-to-right-of-string)

```
SELECT regexp_replace('100 broadway street 100', '(.*)(Street).*', '\1\2', 'i');
```

However, I would like to replace '100 broadway street 100' more flexibly, like this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('100 broadway street 100', '(.*)(Street OR Str. OR Ward OR W. OR Dist).*', '\1\2', 'i');
```

Can someone help me write the right syntax or have any other links I haven't found yet?

Input 1: "100 Alexandre de Rhodes Street, District 10, HCM City"

Input 2: "100 Quang Trung Str., District 10, HCM City"

Input 3: "123 Newton St., GV District, HCM City"
Output 1: "100 ABC Street, Ward 16" 
Output 2: "100 Quang Trung Str."
.v.v..

ie will need to remove the string behind the road name

Comment: Show us some more sample data and the expected result. All as formatted text, i.e. no images.

Comment: Input 1: "100 Alexandre de Rhodes Street, District 10, HCM City" 
Input 2: "100 Quang Trung Str., District 10, HCM City" 
Input 3: "123 Newton St., GV District, HCM City"
Output 1: "100 ABC Street, Ward 16"
Output 2: "100 Quang Trung Str."
....v...v....

ie will need to remove the string behind the road name

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead.

Comment: I will note this for later. I have additional updates at the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `|` operator like this

```
SELECT regexp_replace('100 broadway Dist 100', '(.*)(Street|Str|Ward|Dist).*', '\1\2', 'i');
```

Output

```
100 broadway Dist
```

**Update based on comments**

You can replace `.*` with `.`.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('100 broadway Dist Str 100 Str abc Street', 
                      '(.)(Street|Dist|Ward|Str).*', '\1\2', 'i');
```

Output

```
100 broadway Dist
```

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work when I replace the string with "100 broadway Dist 100 Str abc", the result will produce "100 broadway Dist 100 Str" instead of my desired "100 broadway Dist"

Comment: @ngtonhung , You mean to say the same string may contain both `Dist` and `Str`? If so what is the order of precedence ?

Comment: The order of precedence will be left to right (words that appear first will remove all words to their right)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer solved my problem.

Comment: @ngtonhung, Welcome! Glad i could help.